# Return dynamic class from method

Tags: java, class, methods

I would like to know how I can return a Class object from a method that takes a dynamic string value. I don't know if what I have is the correct way of doing it

```
        public Class getDynClass(String className) { 
              try {
                 Class dynClass = Class.forName(className);
                 return dynClass;
              } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                 // error
                 return null;
              }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: No. I just want to know if this will work. I did not run it yet as this takes some time to build and deploy. So I just want to know if something like this will work.

Comment: Please test it once, if there is any problem, post the exact problem.

Comment: Ok. It woks. how can I add a getter and setter to this dynamic class?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a instance of the Class by this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object object = getDynClass("org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler");
    System.err.println(object);
}

public static Object getDynClass(String className) {
    try {
        Class dynClass = Class.forName(className);
        return dynClass.newInstance();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReadXMLFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting this answer.To return class instance dynamically based on the given string argument.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //long i = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().getMostSignificantBits();    
        Test t = new Test();
        Class<?> obj = t.getDynClass("com.test.TestClass");
    }
     public Class<?> getDynClass(String className) { 
         try {
            Class<?> dynClass = Class.forName(className);
            return dynClass.getClass();
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // error
            return null;
         }
   }
```